# Flutter plugin for Developer page in Play Store

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am developing an app using flutter, I want to give the user an option to see all other apps provided by me on play store. I used to do the same using native android code as below:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=<Developer_ID>")));
```

Does anyone knows about any flutter plugin using which I can achieve the same. Or any flutter sample code using which I can do so.

**Note: I want it to open in the play store, not in the browser.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher).

This example will try to launch Play Store directly and open the browser only if the Play Store app is not installed:

```
  void _launchDeveloperPage() async {
    final devID = '<DEV_ID>';
    final market = 'market://dev?id=$devID';
    final url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=$devID';
    if (await canLaunch(market)) {
      await launch(market);
    } else if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package for launching the AppStore/PlayStore as follows :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchDeveloperPage,
        child: Text('Show All Apps'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_launchDeveloperPage() async {
  const url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=<Developer_ID>';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```